# Fix Primeface's DataTable's poor scrollbar appearance

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

As can be seen here:

[primefaces scrolling DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf)

And in the image:
[image: primefaces table]

When using a vertical scrollbar only, the scrollbar is too far right of the table. This is more obviously displeasing when using dark colored themes.

How do you bring the scrollbar to be flush with the table?

I'm using Primefaces 3.0.1, and the showcase uses the latest snapshot.

Comment: @Daniel: the problem also manifests on the showcase labs page. The showcase labs site uses the latest beta version which is mentioned in the footer of any page, which is currently 3.2-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, just increase your column widths or set a fixed scrollWidth, showcase is 100% for demonstration. If you create an issue ticket, it is likely to be marked as wontfix because there is nothing to fix.

Comment: Having to set the width of all columns, and the scrollWidth, and disable resizable columns seems to makes it work. It may not be a bug, but there is certainly a need for a new feature, as the workaround is excessive. Thanks though.

Comment: I've changed my mind for 3.5 and added some calculation to place scrollbar just next to the last column.

Answer (score 1):

Just a idea: What happens if you try using the scrollWidth="99%" or 100% ? cause in the example the XY make the vertical scrolling look well...